# Joining tables in pyspark based on condition

Tags: join, pyspark, databricks

I would like to join pyspark tables where the first table has `id`, `startTime` and `endTime` where as the second table has `Time` and `value`. The merged table will have for every `id` the columns `Time` and `value` where the `startTime<=Time<=endTime`. The `startTime` and `endTime` among the `id`s may overlap

Comment: what did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming df1 and df2 are your 2 dataframes :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df1.join(
    df2,
    on=F.col("Time").between(F.col("startTime"), F.col("endTime")),
    how="inner",
)
```

Comment: Thanks!. I am testing this. I do get a warning 'Use range join optimization: This query has a join condition that can benefit from range join optimization. To improve performance'. New to databricks and pysparks - do you have nay thoughts on this?